# Issue scraping last page of a Table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I'm currently trying to scrape an internal website's table that has 16 pages. When I run the code below, the table on the last page isn't scraped and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mb4ig/PycharmProjects/Python/Test.py", line 56, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\mb4ig\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

When I select 15 pages, the code runs fine and all 15/16 pages of tables are scraped. The 16th Page is not scraped.

Please can someone assist. Thanks.

```
page=1
max_page=16 # Only works when I select 15 pages but the last page isn't scraped.
name=[]
desc=[]

while page<=max_page:

 rows= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='container']/table/tbody/tr")))
 for row in rows:
    name.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text)
    desc.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text)

 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next'))).click()
 page=page+1
 print('navigate to page: ' + str(page))

driver.close()

df=pd.DataFrame({"Name":name,"Description":desc})
print(df)
df.to_csv('Test.txt',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last page probably doesn't have the `Next` button, or at the very least it's not clickable (it's the last page after all). Check if you are in the last page

```
if page < max_page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next'))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Guy! This works perfectly, appreciate the lightning fast response, it's that quick that I can't accept your answer for another 4 mins! :)